# Editing tool for FIX messages

Tags: fix-protocol

I find myself doing quite a bit of testing lately using FIX messages as test data, and especially for testing, I need to make frequent, small changes.  E.g. right now I would like to use one FIX message supplied by business, to test commission calculations on various allocation amounts.  To change price, quantity, or commission, I would have to recalculate the message checksum, and the body length.  Is there a simple tool I can use that will just do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [Verifix](http://www.greenlinetech.com/products/verifix.php) tools.They usually come with a month of free use for trial packages. They are a good option if you want their software. They provide FIX tools for simulating real time environments and are quite good. I am saying this after having used their tools.

[ValidFix](http://www.validfix.com/fix-analyzer.html) is an online tool for checking for the validity of the FIX messages.

Comment: Wow, I think 'we' (the support account managers) actually use Verifix at work.  I've heard about it, but thought it was part of our messaging hub, not a standalone tool.

Comment: I used verifix and it's really clunky.

Comment: I agree with Chacko. Verifix is awful. I wonder if the question was just a setup to promote it. That being the case my apology: Go go use verifix is awesome (NOT).

Comment: @Xnzo72 - No need to be sarcastic. You are assuming just because you hate it others also need to hate it. It may also depend how people use it and for what means.

Comment: @Zo72, can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: @dainichi sure. Validfix works for us. It costs almost nothing

Answer (score -1):

Our UK based company Cynapps limited makes low-cost lightweight applications for this exact purpose. You can have a look at http://www.cynapps.net/intellioms/. All products have a free trial and we're a friendly bunch of people!